# Some tags are missing from my app using ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, rfid

We have a desktop app which principal goal is to catch all the tags read from RFID readers from different brands. We connect the readers and set a `ThreadPool` for instance of a reader connected. Everything works pretty good when there are 4 or 5 readers connected. The problem starts when there are almost 30 readers connected. A lot of tags are missing. These tags are present in every vehicle. These buses will get into a Land terminal, so we have readers in every zone then we can calculate the bills. In the other hand, 8  or 10 buses will get into the terminal every minute and will go through the majority of readers. My question is, `ThreadPool` is efficient in this case, or should I use another technique?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Client = new TcpClient(pIPReader, pPuerto);
if (Client.GetStream().CanRead)
{
    RX = new StreamReader(Client.GetStream());
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SocketNedapupPass, new object[] { 
    pIPReader,row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().ToUpper(), RX });
}

private void SocketNedapupPass(object obj)
{
        object[] array = obj as object[];
        bool lecturaNueva = false;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        StreamReader SR = (StreamReader)array[2];
       
        string pIPReader = array[0].ToString();
     
        if (SR.BaseStream.CanRead)
        {               
            try
            {                  
                while(SR.BaseStream.CanRead == true)
                {
                   string RawData = SR.ReadLine();
                  
                    if ((RawData.Length - 1) > InicioNedap)
                    {
                        string checkRawData = RawData.Substring(InicioNedap);

                        if (checkRawData.Length >= LongitudNedap)
                        {
                            RawData = checkRawData.Substring(0, LongitudNedap);

                            lecturaNueva = validacionLectura(RawData, 1, pIPReader);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            oLog.WriteSuceso("La placa " + RawData + " no cumple con las 
                            longitudes especificadas en el archivo de configuración");
                        }
                    }
                   
                    if (lecturaNueva)
                    {
                        if (callAccion && spAccion.Length >= 4)
                        {

                                        int codAntena = 1;

                                        if (listaReaderPrincipal.Any(x =>x.serie_punto_control 
                                          == pIPReader && x.es_principal == "2"))
                                        {
                                            //PROCESAR SALIDA PRINCIPAL
                                            ProcesoSalidaPrincipalVehiculo(RawData, pIPReader, 
                                            codAntena, SR);//RX);
                                        }
                                        else if (listaReaderPrincipal.Any(x => 
                                        x.serie_punto_control == pIPReader && x.es_principal 
                                         == "1"))
                                        {
                                            //PROCESAR INGRESO PRINCIPAL
                                            ProcesoIngresoPrincipalVehiculo(RawData, 
                                            pIPReader, codAntena, SR);//RX);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            int res = cnAccion.EjecutarSP(spAccion, RawData, 
                                            codigoAlterno, pIPReader, codAntena);
                                        }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                oLog.WriteError(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SR.Close();
                oLog.WriteError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are asking about the efficiency of the `ThreadPool`, while your problem seems to be related to correctness. Are you searching for a more efficient technique in order to produce more incorrect results, faster?

Comment: Im searching for a more efficient tecnique in order not to miss any tags, because it seems threadpool has some limitations, thats my answer

Comment: Ah, OK, I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

The `ThreadPool` is intended for large numbers of short-lived tasks, in order to amortize the cost of `Thread` creation and destruction. If your program has a need for a specific number of long-running threads, it's better to create these threads explicitly using the `Thread` constructor, instead of relying on the `ThreadPool`. The problem with using the `ThreadPool` for long running tasks is that it might become saturated (it runs out of worker threads), in which case new requests for work are not satisfied immediately but instead they are scheduled for later. Each scheduled work will have to wait until some of the currently running tasks completes. If none of the running tasks completes soon enough, the `ThreadPool` injects new threads in the pool, at a frequency of around one new thread per second (as of .NET 5). The injection algorithm is an undocumented implementation detail, and it might change in later .NET releases. The only control that you have currently over this algorithm, is the [`SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method. With this method you can configure how many threads will be created instantly on demand, before the `ThreadPool` switches to the slow, conservative algorithm. You can set this threshold as high as you want at the start of the program, for example:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 1000);
```

...but in this case the purpose of the `ThreadPool` will have largely been defeated, and the `ThreadPool` could be hardly described as a pool any more.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I will try to work the way you suggest.