# Tasks running asynchronously even though Main method is not declared as async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency, task

I write the code bellow and forgot to declare Main method as async, so my guess was that the `producer` and `consumer` tasks should run synchronously.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace MainProgram;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var intCollection = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        int sum = 0;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running Producer");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                intCollection.Add(i);

                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            intCollection.CompleteAdding();
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running Consumer");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            while (!intCollection.IsCompleted)
            {
                sum += intCollection.Take();
                Console.WriteLine("Thingi Thingi");
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("aaabbb");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But the output of this code looks like this:

```
aaabbb
Running Producer
Running Consumer
0
Thingi Thingi
1
Thingi Thingi
2
Thingi Thingi
3
Thingi Thingi
4
Thingi Thingi
5
Thingi Thingi
6
Thingi Thingi
7
8
9
Thingi Thingi
Thingi Thingi
Thingi Thingi
```

This is to my surprise, because the tasks appear to run asynchronously. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You should do some research into what `Task.Run` actually does. It is literally the way to run tasks asynchronously from a synchronous method. You can't call asynchronous methods using `await` if your method is not declared `async`. That is where you can only call methods synchronously.

Comment: This is expected behaviour.  You start the first Task, and then execution continues with starting the second Task.  You are not awaiting the Result of either, so execution continues regardless.  Then as each task progresses, you get the successive messages

Comment: Task.Run will still run the code inside asynchronously [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-action)). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/18278998) might help you resolve your issue in a better way

Comment: `async` doesn't make things run asynchronously (it is purely syntactic). It only allows you to use `await`.

Comment: As a side-note, there is a race condition in the consumer loop `while (!intCollection.IsCompleted)`. The correct way to consume a `BlockingCollection<T>` is the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) method. It's not the only correct way, but it's the simplest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method invokes the `action` delegate on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool). So after calling twice this method, the `ThreadPool` spawned 2 threads to handle the request for work. At that point your program had at least 3 threads alive: the main thread of the process, and 2 background threads owned by the `ThreadPool`. Seeing the two background threads running concurrently is the expected behavior. Whether the `Main` method is `async` is irrelevant.

In case you had invoked the `Task.Run` 100 times, the `ThreadPool` wouldn't have spawned 100 threads instantly to satisfy the demand. You can find a description of `ThreadPool`'s algorithm that creates and destroys threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328524/are-there-more-tasks-being-performed-than-threads-whats-happening/73328718#73328718) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456509/some-tags-are-missing-from-my-app-using-threadpool/69458208#69458208). It is not very complicated. It involves a threshold that is equal to the number of CPU cores in your machine, and is adjustable with the [`SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) API.